# How to stop admob adview?

Tags: admob, destroy

My problem is how to code adview admob comlete stop when exit on application. I have try this but i start getin error. It say adView cannot be resolved ?

My code:

```
      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {

           if (mp != null) {
               mp.release();
               mp = null; 
              }
         super.onDestroy();
         adView.destroy();




      }



}
```

Comment: `adView` is declared as a field in your Activity?

Comment: Exactly! now it works and no error message. But seems that admob still run in the background when i exit on app, no matter i use home or back button, and the CPU meter shows 30% -40%, even more. I have try completle without admob and then application works fine and clear CPU. What could be wrong??